# Python DataFrame: Filter a dataframe dates based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter the df by `start_date`.

`start_date` will be same for each user. If any record in `present_dates` is less than `start_date`, then those have to be filtered out by user.

sample df

```
                name      present_dates                     start_date
        0       bruno    2021-03-08 10:09:37.623        2021-04-01 10:09:37.623
        1       bruno    2021-05-08 10:09:37.623        2021-04-01 10:09:37.623
        2       bruno    2021-06-08 10:09:37.623        2021-04-01 10:09:37.623
        3       paul     2021-02-24 10:09:37.623        2021-01-25 10:09:37.623
        4       paul     2021-01-15 10:09:37.623        2021-01-25 10:09:37.623
        5       marcus   2021-06-08 10:09:37.623        2021-10-15 10:09:37.623
        6       luke     2021-01-05 10:09:37.623        2021-01-01 10:09:37.623
```

Expected Output

```
                name      present_dates                     start_date
        0       bruno    2021-05-08 10:09:37.623        2021-04-01 10:09:37.623
        1       bruno    2021-06-08 10:09:37.623        2021-04-01 10:09:37.623
        2       paul     2021-02-24 10:09:37.623        2021-01-25 10:09:37.623
        3       luke     2021-01-05 10:09:37.623        2021-01-01 10:09:37.623
```

Comment: this is plain boolean indexing: `df[df['start_date']<df['present_dates']]`

Comment: You dont need to group on names,as it is a row wise comparison. But if you need to sort, chain a `.sort_values('name')` later

Answer (score 0):

you can use boolean indexing as anky mentioned, and you could also use `df.query()` such as:

```
df.query("start_date < present_date")
```